# printing hostnames of PCs on the network using nmap (Python)

Tags: python, nmap

I am using python2.7 and trying to scan my network and print the host names of PCs on my n/w , i looked up on official docs of [nmap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-nmap) , i tried but its not working i don't know why . Kindly guide me through the process or tell me where i am going wrong . Thanks in advance :)

```
hosts_list = [(x, nm[x]['status']['state'],nm[x].hostname()) for x in nm.all_hosts()]
   for host, status,name in hosts_list:
      print('{0}:{1}:{2}'.format(host, status,name))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the first line of your link:

```
This is a python class to use nmap and access scan results from python3
```

And you said that you're using 2.7... Check that, may be your problem.

Comment: I tried libnmap but it is only able to show my local computer's name as localhost it doesnn't shows names of other PCs on my n/w . what should i do now ? any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [sacket](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/socket.html) to get `host name`

```
import socket
import nmap

nm = nmap.PortScanner()
nm.scan(hosts='192.168.1.0/24', arguments='-n -sP -PE -PA21,23,80,3389')

hosts_list = [(x, nm[x]['status']['state'],socket.gethostbyaddr(x)[0]) for x in nm.all_hosts() if socket.gethostbyaddr(x)[0]]
for host, status,name in hosts_list:
  print('{0}:{1}:{2}'.format(host, status,name))
```

output:

```
192.168.1.1:up:TP-LINK
192.168.1.102:up:android-XXX
192.168.1.105:up:DESKTOP-XXX
192.168.1.107:up:android-XXX
```